# TableView Changes Frame When I Scroll the ScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, ios5

I have a view with ScrollView.

I have two UIView and Two TableView on it.

I want the view to be expandable and collapsable.

I have taken two views as I cannot hide a part of UIView.

What I did is I hide the second View Initially via XIB and On click of a button which is  on FirstView, I unhide the second View which I placed just below the FirstView

Now, Since I have Two TableView which should be displayed below the first view and should change their frame to appear below the subView (SecondView), when subView (SecondView) is not hidden.

I placed the First Table below the First View and above the Hidden View (SecondView) and second Table Below the First Table.

So when I click a button on first view I hide that button and unhide the SecondView and change the tableVC frame so that it appears below the Second View.

Similarly, when I click a button on second view I hide that button and I hide the SecondView and unhide the button on first View and change the tableVC frame so that it appears below the First View i.e. Initial Position.

These screen shots might be useful:

[image]

**Gray portion is the first table and Pink portion is the second table.**

[image]

**Green Portion is the expanded View which was hidden and the tableVC (Gray) was on top of it.**

**Now everything was working just fine , when i encountered that when i scroll, the table view changes its frame randomly. When i expand the firstView and scroll the table changes its frame and moves upwards. Similarly when i collapse and Scroll the same thing happens.**

Here's the screenshot(Image While I scroll).

[image]

Here's my Code:

```
-(IBAction)expand:(id)sender{
    
    if (addButton){
        [addButton setHidden:YES];
        [subView setHidden:NO];
        [objTableViewForServices setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 310, 306, 136)];
        [objTableViewForManagement setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 480, 306, 136)];
        objScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,700);

    }
}

-(IBAction)collapse:(id)sender{
    if (subButton){
        [subView setHidden:YES];
        [addButton setHidden:NO];
        
        [objTableViewForServices setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 229, 306, 136)];
        [objTableViewForManagement setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 396, 306, 136)];
        objScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,650);

    }
}
```

Probably some scroll problem.

Comment: The coordinates seem a little weird to me. When collapsing you are only decreasing 50 from the content height, but the first tableView will move more than that. Are you sure the frames for the table views are correct?

Comment: @AndreiStanescu : even if the frames are not correctly set and there is some kind of gap between the tables we can adjust the frame to make it appear where we want.My concern is why the scroll view is behaving this way.

Comment: @AndreiStanescu : if required i can send you a demo so that you can have a clear picture/idea.

Comment: That would be excellent.  Please send.

Comment: @AndreiStanescu : Your email Address please !!!

Comment: reydan_ro at yahoo dot com

Answer (score 0):

ITs because of autolayout & constraint . There are two solutions ,

1) Remove auto layout property of scrollview

2) If you want autolayout , then use proper constraint